# Mongoose - Increment with findOne

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm working on some query with Mongoose where I need to skip and limit subdocuments, but in the same query I want to increment some field in document. Currently is my query built with chaining, because I got a lot of problem when I tried to do it just with options. This is what I have:

```
Model.findOne({ shorten_id: id }).select('title content comments views').slice('comments', [0, 10]).exec(function(err, db_res) { if (err) { throw err; } else { console.log(db_res); } });
```

I would like to increment filed 'views' for 1 when calling this query, but as I said, I tried a lot of things and it just didn't work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [`findOneAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) to modify a document while also fetching one.

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate({ shorten_id: id }, { $inc: { fieldToIncrement: 1 })
  .select('title content comments views')
  .slice('comments', [0, 10])
  .exec(function(err, db_res) { 
    if (err) { 
      throw err; 
    } 
    else { 
      console.log(db_res); 
    } 
  });
```

Comment: You are missing a bracket after the $inc

Comment: please note: fieldToIncrement still not increase in variable db_res

Comment: Sorry for the noob-iness, but where does $inc come from? I'm not sure I understand that part?

Comment: @trainoasis `$inc` is a MongoDB update operator, see the documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/